# CodeIgniter - Only allowed view your own profile, else 404

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter controller function like this:

```
class User extends MY_Controller{
    public function view($user_id)
    {
        if($user_id!==$this->get_session_user_id()){show_404();}
        // ...
```

I only want each user to be allowed to view their own data, for example, you can only view your own profile.

QUESTION:
The code above seems to do the trick,  but Im just wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Better way, check if user is logged-in & get his id from the session without having to pass the user_id to it will be "user/view" instead of "user/view/$id"

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter provides a rather sparse set of tools for you to do what you need to do. It doesn't even know what a user is out of the box.

There might be a dozen other ways of achieving the desired effect, but if yours works, then it works.